# How to count all digits after 2 digits, but before the decimal?

Tags: c#

```
decimal n = str.Split('.')[0].Substring(2).Where(d => d == '0').Count(s => s == '0');
                            displayLabel5.Text = n.ToString();
```

This code works, but it only counts the zeros after the first 2 digits I input. After I enter, let's say, 5360000. It will output 4 because there are 4 zeroes. but I want it also to count the 6 because it isnt apart of the first 2 numbers.

Comment: `decimal n = str.Split('.')[0].Substring(2).Length;`

Comment: That of course assumes that your `str` contains a decimal, and there are at least 2 digits to the left of it.

Comment: @dubstylee Only the second part is true `there are at least 2 digits to the left of it` . Nothing wrong with `"".Split('.')[0]`

Comment: @EZI right, but `"".Split('.')[0].Substring(2)` will not work.  I suppose that `"some other string with no decimal".Split('.')[0].Substring(2)` would work though.  Also, my suggestion does not restrict the count to simply digits, so that is another assumption as well :)

Comment: To avoid exceptions : n = str.Split('.')[0].PadLeft(2,'0').Substring(2).Length;

Comment: well you are counting only zeros, that's way your output is 4, @dubstylee comment is the right answer.

Comment: What should this return for "10" and "1"?

Answer (score 1):

The following code takes all the characters that are before the decimal mark '.' then it skips the first two and counts the remaing ones.

```
var test = "335434553.23434";
var result = test.TakeWhile(d => d != '.').Skip(2).Count();
```

Note that the code assumes that you are dealing with a string that represents a valid number.